# How can i convert a raster from continuous to discrete?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-conversion, geotiff-tiff

I have a tiff that is 'invalid' for a lot of tools and will not let me view the attribute table. I think this is because it is "continuous" rather than "discrete".

Does anybody know how to convert it or make arcgis treat it as a discreet raster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your raster is in 32-bit floating point format, you will be unable to [build a raster attribute table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m2000000).  Only single band integer raster datasets are valid inputs.  Check the format by right-clicking the raster layer in the table of contents > Properties > Source > Pixel Depth/PixelType.  You may want to decrease the bit depth to, for example, 8-bit signed using [Copy Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000094000000).

Keep in mind that this will effect the data structure.  For example, reducing the bit depth to 8-bit unsigned on a land cover dataset with values ranging from 0 - 255 would be appropriate.  However, reducing the bit depth on high precision aerial imagery would result in the loss of potentially valuable data.

*Additional Resources:*

- [Bit depth capacity for raster dataset cells](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000002s000000)
- [Supported raster dataset file formats](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000000q000000)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use raster calculator. Input the min & max range of your continuous raster, so when you do raster calculator, just double click your tiff layer, and say >= (your min value) & tiff layer <= (your max value). The output from raster calculator should be discrete unspecified integer. What it will do is everything in your processing extent that is within that min/max range will = 1, and everything that is not within your min/max range, but is in your processing extent will = 0.